# Adding a row on top-1 position in html table

Tags: javascript, html

```
function addRowtoTop(first) {
// get input values
var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
var country = document.getElementById('country').value;



// get the html table
// 0 = the first table
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

// add new empty row to the table
// 0 = in the top 
// table.rows.length = the end
// table.rows.length/2+1 = the center
var newRow = table.insertRow((table.rows.length / 0));'
```

i have been trying to add a row on top-1 position on a html table but cant figure out how. by this line `var newRow = table.insertRow((table.rows.length / 0));` i am able to add the row on top but it gets added above the heading part. Thanks in advance

Comment: is that right when you try to `table.rows.length / 0` divide zero?and if you change you table add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` then it will insert into tbody

Comment: that line adds the row to the top but what i want is the row to be added below top(top-1).

Answer (score 1):

you need to store the head in a variable, then the new row and then take the rest of the rows,
at the end, just table.innerHTML = newTable;

```js
function addRow(){
        var table = document.querySelector('table');
        
        var Head = table.children[0].children[0].outerHTML;
        var newRow = '<tr><td>newShoes</td><td>Shoes</td><td>Shoes</td></tr>';
        var restOfTheTable = '';
        for(var i = 1; i<=table.children[0].children.length-1; i++){
            restOfTheTable += (table.children[0].children[i].outerHTML);
        }
        table.innerHTML = `${Head}${newRow}${restOfTheTable}`;
    }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Location</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>Shoes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>Shoes</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<button onclick="addRow()">add row</button>
```